# Question about irreducible polynomials in algebraically closed fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

A tipical question in the past exams of a commutative algebra course is to determine if a ring of the form $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is an integral domain, usually with $1\le n \le 3$. Suppose that $k$ is algebraically closed and $n=2$ or $3$ to begin. How should I approach this type of problems? What tools of algebraic geometry/commutative algebra should I use?

Comment: You need to show that $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: Yes equivalently I'm asking how to prove that a polynomial in two three variables is irreducible (in an algebraically closed field)

Comment: There are many ways. For example, use Eisenstein, or just prove by contradiction: assume $f=gh$ and get a contradiction. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14076/irreducibility-of-polynomials-in-two-variables